# Using apply to run functions over subset of time series

Tags: r, time-series, subset, apply

I am doing a project looking at forecasting province-level violence in Iraq. The data I have is monthly data on four parameters (alpha, lambda, tau, and beta) for all 19 of the provinces. I am  trying to predict each of the four parameters in each province separately using a linear model controlling for trend and seasonal components with the `forecast` function in the `forecast` package in R (more complex models to come:). The example code below displays the code and quantities I am interested in for the first province (Al-Anbar). However, I would like to use the apply family of functions to have a more parsimonious way of doing this for all provinces (alpha, lambda, tau, and beta for each province), instead of doing each province one by one. For instance, I want to subset the data by province using `df_list<-split(main_data, provinces)`. Then I want to declare each province within the `df_list` a `ts` object, and then run the forecast functions for each parameter (alpha, lambda, tau, and beta) in each province using an `apply` function. Any suggestion on a hand way to do this efficiently? Thanks!

```
library(forecast)



main_data<-read.csv("Iraq_by_province_2004-2009.csv", header=TRUE)

attach(main_data)

  date        province  alpha     lambda    tau   beta 
1     7/24/04 Al-Anbar   0.0       0.0       0.0   0.00             
2     8/23/04 Al-Anbar   0.0       0.0       0.0   0.00             
3     9/22/04 Al-Anbar   2.0       1.5       3.5   0.55        
4    10/22/04 Al-Anbar   2.4       1.5       3.4   0.10 
.      .      .          .         .         .     .
.      .      .          .         .         .     .
.      .      .          .         .         .     .
1008  1/29/09 Wasit      0.0        0.0      0.0   0.00       



###Al Anbar Province##
al_anbar<-subset(main_data, province=="Al-Anbar")



  #Alpha
  al_anbar_alpha<-ts(al_anbar$alpha, frequency=12, start=c(2004, 7))

  fit_alpha <- tslm(al_anbar_alpha ~ trend + season)

  forecast(fit_alpha, h=4, level=c(68,95), fan=FALSE,
   ts=TRUE)

   #Lambda
  al_anbar_lambda<-ts(al_anbar$lambda, frequency=12, start=c(2004, 7))

  fit_lambda<- tslm(al_anbar_lambda ~ trend + season)

  forecast(fit_lambda, h=4, level=c(68,95), fan=FALSE,
   ts=TRUE)

  #Tau
  al_anbar_tau<-ts(al_anbar$tau, frequency=12, start=c(2004, 7))

  fit_tau<- tslm(al_anbar_tau ~ trend + season)

  forecast(fit_tau, h=4, level=c(68,95), fan=FALSE,
   ts=TRUE)

  #Beta
  al_anbar_beta<-ts(al_anbar$lambda, frequency=12, start=c(2004, 7))

  fit_beta<- tslm(al_anbar_beta~ trend + season)

  forecast(fit_beta, h=4, level=c(68,95), fan=FALSE,
   ts=TRUE)
```

Comment: You want the ["split-apply-combine"](http://www.jstatsoft.org/v40/i01/paper) approach. There are a number of functions implementing that. Those in package plyr offer a nice syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your data in the long format using `reshape2` then apply `ddply` from plyr for each region.

```
library(reshape2)
dat.m <- melt(dat,id.vars=c('date','province'))
library(plyr)

ddply(dat.m,.(province),function(ts){
## each ts looks like this (here for alpha)
## you can process it 
# date province variable      value
# 1 2014-09-21  region1    alpha  0.3981059
# 2 2015-01-06  region1    alpha -0.6120264


})
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks agstudy and Roland! So I used a slightly modified version of `ddply` and was able to get it to work. The example code is below. Thanks again.

```
library(plyr)

main_data<-read.csv("Iraq_by_province_2004-2009.csv", header=TRUE)

attach(main_data)


##Alpha
alpha_function = function(x) {
   ts_alpha<-ts(x$alpha, frequency=12, start=c(2004, 7))
    fit_alpha <- tslm(ts_alpha~ trend + season, )
    return(data.frame(forecast(fit_alpha, h=4, level=c(68,95), fan=FALSE,
        ts=TRUE)))               
}

ddply(main_data, .(province), alpha_function)
```

Comment: iF you put in the long format using melt( as I show oin my answer) , you can use the same function for all greeks, in the function above you change x$alpha by x$value.

Comment: Ah, very clever! This was a demo code, so I will use your code format going forward. Thanks again!